# looking back at or looking back on?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When remembering events from last year, would you say "looking back on 2017" or "looking back at 2017"?

Comment: That looks like a matter of style and personal choice, unless there are important details…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic expression is ***[look back on](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/look-back)*** something:

> to think about a time or event in the past.
>
> - Most people look back on their school days with fondness.

(Macmillan Dictionary)